# Swiper.js autoplay not working after `removeAllSlides` and then `appendSlide`

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I use Swiper.js to generate a autoplayed slide container with dynamic slides.

```
var sw = new Swiper({autoplay: 2000});
sw.appendSlide(slide);
sw.removeAllSlides(); // or remove the only one left slide with sw.removeSlide(the_only_slide_left);
sw.appendSlide(slide1);
sw.appendSlide(slide2);
```

I expected that slide1, slide2 is autoplaying now, but slide2 is showing forever.

I also tried to add the following param to Swiper.

```
observer: true
```

It does not work as I expected, either.

---

Updated:

```
var sw = new Swiper({autoplay: 2000});
sw.appendSlide(slide);
sw.removeAllSlides(); // or remove the only one left slide with sw.removeSlide(the_only_slide_left);
sw.udpate();
sw.appendSlide(slide1);
sw.appendSlide(slide2);
sw.update();
```

still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `mySwiper.update(updateTranslate); Once you do manual add/remove`. As per [documentation](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#.WPSW1dKGOM8)

Comment: Thank you. Any other method should I call? It still does not work after I call `.update()`.